In GODOT Why sprite doesn't get new position?
The sprite should move and change its initial position when I drag it. Animation doesn't work too. Help me pls [enter image description here] ((https://i.sstatic.net/tt2oRwyf.png))(enter image description here)
THERE LINK ON video if you want! https://youtu.be/Nt5IN6wh4ms
I've been changing centration and position, but it's no use.

My dude. Welcome to Stack Overflow, but have you seen Stack Overflow? Please post your code as text using the markdown syntax.
In any case, you are not changing the player’s position, you’re setting it, basically. Try using += to add a small distance to the current position, instead of always resetting it:
global_position.x += direction * delta * speed

Better yet, use move_and_slide():
velocity.x = direction.x * speed
move_and_slide()

Here you don’t need delta. move_and_slide() calculates it for you automatically.
